# htaccess redirect to static html hosted within Wordpress root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have a static HTML file hosted in the root folder of my Wordpress install. I can access the URL `http://example.com/er_trends_download` but get an internal server error when the trailing slash is added to the URL: `http://example.com/er_trends_download/`

I have added lines to the `.htaccess` file to drop the `.html` from my static file and my permalink settings in WordPress are set to drop the trailing slash also. I don't have a preference on keeping the trailing slash or not, I would just like to not get the internal server error whether it is part of the URL or not. I've included my full `.htaccess` file below:

```
# Use PHP5.6 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

php_value memory_limit 512M

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
> ```

The problem with this code, is that when the request ends in a slash (eg. `http://example.com/er_trends_download/`) then the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable does not include the trailing slash, but the `REQUEST_URI` variable does. So, you end up rewriting to `/er_trends_download/.html` (which is clearly wrong), but then this results in a rewrite loop... `/er_trends_download/.html.html` to `/er_trends_download/.html.html.html`, etc. and the server eventually breaks with a 500 error.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

This makes the trailing slash optional and the non-greedy pattern `.+?` ensures we grab everything up to, but not including, the trailing slash (if there is one). The `NC` flag is not required here.

So, this allows URLs with and without a trailing slash (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick, I just had to change the .php in your code suggestion to .html

If you could make this edit in your response I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, yes, the `.php` was force of habit (now updated)!